# Datatables in laravel - yajra plugin showing raw data

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, server-side

Actually i am trying to use datatables plugin in laravel, it worked well without serverside. To work with serverside i came across yajra-datatables plugin.

Added.

```
"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0"
```

and service provider,

```
Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,
```

routes file,

```
    use App\Data;
    use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
    Route::get ( '/', function () {
        $data = Data::all ();
        return Datatables::of ( $data )->make ();
    } );
```

javascript,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax : '/'
} );
```

what is that am missing, i 've tried adding columns too,

```
   "columns": [
                    {data: 'id',name:'id' },
                    .....
                    .....
                ]
```

every time i run, its showing raw data, instead of showing in the table view.

### Update : html

```
        <table class="table" id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">#</th>
                    <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
                    .....
                    .....
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

Comment: show me how your html looks?

Comment: I 've updated my question with html @Jaimin

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a small detail here

try changing this

```
return Datatables::of ( $data )->make ();
```

to

```
 return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
```

as per [Yajra datatable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)

Comment: try changing `$data = Data::all ();` to `$data = Data::select('column1','column2')->get();`